# How was the Nasi allowed to diminish the honor of a torah scholar?

Tags: rabbis, kavod, masechet-horayot

In Horiyot 13b it recounts that Rabbi Shimon ben Gamliel made a edict that, as opposed to previously where all people stood for both the Nasi and the 'Chacham', now all people should stand for the Nasi but that for the chacham the person nearest them stands while the others sit. However in kiddushin 32a and Bava Kama 41b it implies that the honor for a torah sage is paramount, being compared to (l'havdil) God's.

If this is the case I would like to understand how R' Shimon was allowed to make this decree if it lessened the honor of a torah sage. If the answer is something along the lines of - he wasn't allowed but he did it anyway - please cite a source.

Comment: Keeping in mind, of course, that the Nasi was a  great Talmid Chacham himself, by definition. Maybe RSbG felt that to properly honor the "bigger" T.Ch you have to show less respect to the junior ones?

Comment: @DannySchoemann not sure what you mean by "by definition". Clearly this Nasi did not know Uktzin until the incident

Comment: OTOH he was capable of learning it by hearing somebody reciting it once from behind his door. Hardly a "beginner", you have to admit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Artscroll there writes that he actually did it to *preserve* their honor, but Rebbe Meir and Rebbe Nassan misunderstood, thus leading to the story that follows.

Comment: As far as knowing Uktzin, are you referring to Rabban Gamliel or RSbG? It was Rabban Gamliel who didn't know Uktzin.